# How do I configure NeoVim in termux?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I install neovim in termux

And run these commands:-

```
cd ~
mkdir .config
cd .config/
mkdir nvim
cd nvim/
nvim init.vim
```

I put `set number` in the init.vim file and save it.

Nothing happens.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Can you precise what do you expect? Is nvim starting? Do you have problem with nvim not considering your int.vim? We would like to get more information about your problem.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt It's not considering my init.vim everything else is fine.

Comment: I understand: you have a file ``~/.config/nvim/init.vim`` containing the line ``set number``. When you restart nvim the ``set number`` is not taken into consideration. Can you tell me what is the value of the environment variable: `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I know how to check and also I am not a root user.

Comment: Could you in a console type `echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and let us know the result?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt It's value is set to nothing.

Comment: Thanks Mohd. What is you start nvim as `nvim -u ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`? Is it considered correctly?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thank you, I will try

Comment: You may also want to run `:echo $MYVIMRC` to inspect what it's set to.